# xargs with command that open editor leaves shell in weird state

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, vi

I tried to make an alias for committing several different git projects.  I tried something like

```
cat projectPaths | \
xargs -I project git --git-dir=project/.git --work-tree=project commit -a
```

where projectPaths is a file containing the paths to all the projects I want to commit.  This seems to work for the most part, firing up vi in sequence for each project so that I can write a commit msg for it.  I do, however, get a msg:

> "Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal"

and afterward my terminal is weird: it doesn't show the text I type and doesn't seem to output any newlines.  When I enter "reset" things pretty much back to normal, but clearly I'm doing something wrong.

Is there some way to get the same behavior without messing up my shell?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that since you're running xargs (and hence git and hence vim) in a pipeline, its stdin is taken from the output of `cat projectPaths` rather than the terminal; this is confusing vim.  Fortunately, the solution is simple: add the `-o` flag to xargs, and it'll start git (and hence vim) with input from /dev/tty, instead of its own stdin.

Comment: awesome this worked great for me (mac), though ole tange mentions below it won't work for all versions of xargs.  thanks!

Answer (score 18):

Using the simpler example of

```
ls *.h | xargs vim
```

here are a few ways to fix the problem:

```
xargs -a <( ls *.h ) vim
```

or

```
vim $( ls *.h | xargs )
```

or

```
ls *.h | xargs -o vim
```

The **first** example uses the xargs `-a` (`--arg-file`) flag which tells xargs to take its input from a file rather than standard input. The file we give it in this case is a bash [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) rather than a regular file.

Process substitution takes the output of the command contained in `<( )` places it in a filedescriptor and then substitutes the filedescriptor, in this case the substituted command would be something like `xargs -a /dev/fd/63 vim`.

The **second** command uses [command substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst), the commands are executed in a subshell, and their stdout data is substituted.

The **third** command uses the xargs `--open-tty` (`-o`) flag, which the man page describes thusly:

> Reopen stdin as /dev/tty in the child process before executing the
>   command.  This is useful if you want xargs to run an interactive
>   application.

If you do use it the old way and want to get your terminal to behave again you can use the `reset` command.

Comment: Thanks. I adapted this to work with the following command `vim $( fgrep -rilZ "foobar" * | xargs -0)` (there may be a more simple way to do this)

Comment: i'm glad for the workaround, but i'd much rather have an xargs that can launch interactive programs successfully, even when stdin has already been used. the -o option is super useful and should be added to GNU.

Comment: Small addition: When issuing `:x` / `:q` / etc. after editing the first file, Vim will complain `# more files to edit`. In order to go to the next file, use `:n`

Answer (score 3):

The man page for GNU `xargs` shows a similar command for emacs:

```
xargs sh -c 'emacs "$@" < /dev/tty' emacs
```

(in this command, the second "emacs" is the "dummy string" that wisbucky refers to in a comment to this answer)

and says this:

> ```
>    Launches  the  minimum  number of copies of Emacs needed, one after the
>    other, to edit the files listed on xargs' standard input.  This example
>    achieves the same effect as BSD's -o option, but in a more flexible and
>    portable way.
> ```

Another thing to try is using `-a` instead of `cat`:

```
xargs -a projectPaths -I project git --git-dir=project/.git --work-tree=project commit -a
```

or some combination of the two.

Comment: I have not seen anyone who can explain how that GNU xargs command is at all helpful for the common application of piping into vim. The closest suggestion I've gotten from anyone is ls|xargs sh -c 'vim "$@" < /dev/tty' but that only echoes the first ls file. I would really like be to able to write a pipe into xargs and still have an xargs that work with interactive applications. GNU, doesnt, and the manual only further confuses that fact.

Comment: Why would you want to pipe `ls` into `xargs`? Can't you just do `vim *` and let `vim` handle the fact that there are multiple files?

Comment: It's an example? Maybe you should try imagining a more complex command Dennis? vim $(hairly|ass|combo) kind of works but I don't see any reason why xargs ought remain awful at dealing with interactive programs, and many people are more comfortable using pipes to stage execution than they are backticks.

Comment: @rektide: The reason that `xargs` doesn't seem to work with with interactive programs is the same as for any other attempt to use interactive programs in a pipe: `stdin` is in use by the pipe and there's no `tty`. It's not specific to `xargs`, for example - you have to use special options to use `ssh` inside a `while read` loop. The authors of GNU `xargs` have chosen not to create such a special option for it - in contrast to the BSD version.

Comment: @rektide *"The closest suggestion I've gotten from anyone is ls|xargs sh -c 'vim "$@" < /dev/tty' but that only echoes the first ls file."* Actually, that is not the correct syntax. It is missing a dummy string at the end. See working solution for GNU xargs: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/410/terminal-borked-after-invoking-vim-with-xargs/17813#17813

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU Parallel http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ installed you should be able to do this:

```
cat projectPaths |
parallel -uj1 git --git-dir={}/.git --work-tree={} commit -a
```

In general this works too:

```
cat filelist | parallel -Xuj1 $EDITOR
```

in case you want to edit more than one file at a time (and you have set $EDITOR to your favorite editor).

`-o` for `xargs` (as mentioned elsewhere) only works for some versions of `xargs` (notably it does not work for GNU xargs).

Watch the intro video to learn more about GNU Parallel http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ

Comment: The parallel $EDITOR example you show still results in the same detached tty for me. "Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal" Do you have any other things we should try that might work?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting! I see the exact same behaviour on Mac as well, doing something as simple as:

ls *.h | xargs vim

Apparently, it is a problem with vim:

http://talideon.com/weblog/2007/03/xargs-vim.cfm

Comment: no it's not vim, it's how pipes work. on mac you can probably do ls *.h|xargs -o vim and it works, because that xargs has a command line option which allows it to reattach the terminal, but i don't have a BSD to test against.