# Using a pipe within a bash alias

Tags: bash, pipe, alias

I don't have experience in shell scripting, so I'm unable to see the problem of the following situation:

I have defined an alias of the following form(`file.c` is located in `~/dir`):

```
alias code="cd ~/dir | vim file.c"
```

When inputting it, I get the following warning, and the proper files aren't opened:

```
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
2 files to edit
```

I thought that the pipe operator in this instance would separate the two commands, first changing the directory, then opening the file.

Comment: Maybe this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852616/xargs-with-command-that-open-editor-leaves-shell-in-weird-state

Answer (score 5):

Since you mention you don't have experience in shell, I will be verbose.

The problem is that you are using the pipe wrong.

```
cmd1 | cmd2
```

Means redirecting the output of cmd1 to the input of cmd2.
Maybe you are confusing it with the OR operator ||, which can be used as:

```
cmd1 || cmd2
```

"If cmd1 is not successful, execute cmd2". This would not help you in your case, though.
Both previous answers work for you:

```
alias code="cd ~/dir; vim file.c"
```

Using the semicolon, which is just a simple command separator. Or my personal favorite

```
alias code="cd ~/dir && vim file.c"
```

Which uses the AND operator.

```
cmd1 && cmd2
```

means "do cmd1. If it is successful, proceed with cmd2. Otherwise, stop".

Comment: maybe the user had the wrong use case in mind but it still would be nice if you answered the question asked, maybe providing an example of a bash alias with a pipe command in it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need pipe. Use semicolon that is command separator.

```
alias code="cd ~/dir; vim file.c"
```

You can also use [pushd and popd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushd_and_popd) in alias to return to previous directory.

Answer (score 3):

A better alias would be:

```
alias code="cd ~/dir && vim file.c && cd -"
```

This will ensure you are not opening file in your current directory if `cd` failed and return to the old directory where you were.